# Dynamically resizing Angular Smart Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, smart-table

I'm working on a project where I'm using Angular-Gridster to have moveable widgets.

One of these widgets contains a smart table. What I want to accomplish is to have the table snap to the widget size when I resize it, and on the initial load of the page.

I also want to dynamically determine the number of rows to shown on a page based on the bounds of the widget box. This one I have an idea of how to accomplish. It is the previous stuff I'm having difficulty with.

For charts and other things for widgets I've used something like

```
var el = element.closest('.gridster-item');
```

Which gets me the gridster container my table is in. I also know the gridster-item-resized event to use.

But how do I use these to dynamically resize my table. Unlike a chart library like Highcharts, there's no watch applied on properties.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: not clear why this can't be done with css, or what html structure you are using. Presumably you are resizing an outer container not the table itself

Comment: @charlietfl The container is resizable. However, when the container the table is in resizes, the table itself needs to resize to fit within the container, or else I get the issue of it overflowing.

Comment: not sure how we can help without knowing css used. A demo would help